# Getting error while trying to invoke a powershell command on a remote machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, invoke, powershell-remoting

machineName have tried executing a script using invoke-command in the following way:

```
 Invoke-command -filepath C:\scripts\GettMembers.ps1 -computername "machinename" -credential $Getcredential
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be resolved. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

But I was able to add the machine to the trusted hosts of the local machine using the following command :

```
winrm set winrm/config/client `@{TrustedHosts="machineName"}'
```

Comment: So presumably you command actually looks like this: `Invoke-Command -computername madhsubr-lap.idc.oracle.com ...`?  That is, your not really using "machinename", right? :-)  Have you tried nslookup on madhsubr-lap.idc.oracle.com?

Comment: Seems to be a name resolution (DNS) error. Try `nslookup <remotecomputer>`

Comment: That was a mistake.I am using machine name itself,i.e, the machine name used in the invoke-command and the winrm set command is the same. I tried running nslook up on the machine.I am getting the following exception:'can't find machineName: Non-existent domain'

Answer (score 5):

The problem appears to be that "machinename" isn't something your DNS knows how to resolve. This isn't a powershell problem, but rather a system configuration problem.

You can verify this by asking powershell to resolve the machine name with something like this:

```
$machine = "machinename"
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($machine)
```

If you get an error, that means that you're using a machine name that can't be resolved (ie: windows can't convert "machinename" to an IP address). It's not a matter of trust or permissions, it's that your computer doesn't think "machinename" is a valid machine on your network.

Have you tried using a fully qualified address (eg: machinename.mycompany.com)?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error on two servers that were configured for DNS and could ping the target. The resolution was this command:

**netsh winhttp reset proxy**

Credit to the following blog:
http://directaccessguide.com/2014/03/05/winrm-client-errors-in-remote-access-console/

Comment: Although completely unlikely, this saved our problem after days of experimenting!

Answer (score -1):

Just installed Exchange 2016 en had the "The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be resolved" problem. Removed winhttp proxy setting and BAM!